# Difference between DIV=calc and default DIV for Koma Script class scrbook

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, typearea

I find strange in the example bellow that when I activate the option DIV=calc for the document class scrbook the calculated DIV value for the document becomes different than the predifined values in Table2.2 of the Koma Script manual.

Normaly, the DIV=calc option is supposed to optimize the DIV value for a given paper and font size.

In the following example, A4 paper is selected without specifying a font size. Therfore, logically the calculated DIV value must be the same as the predifined one, or not ?

First example

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,twoside,BCOR=2.5mm,DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter Koma has selected the following DIV value: $$DIV = \the\ta@div$$ and the following BCOR value $$BCOR = \the\ta@bcor$$ \makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image: First output]

and when removing the option DIV=calc :

[image: Second output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All KOMA-Script classes use `DIV=default` by default. The symbolic value `default` means: Calculate type area using the standard value for the current page format and current font size. If no standard value exists, `calc` is used.

The standard `DIV` values can be find in a table in the documentation:

- `paper=a4` and `fontsize=10pt` -> standard `DIV` value: 8
- `paper=a4` and `fontsize=11pt` -> standard `DIV` value: 10
- `paper=a4` and `fontsize=12pt` -> standard `DIV` value: 12

In your example there is `paper=a4`, `fontsize=11pt` (default), so `DIV=default` results in `DIV=10`.

The standard values does not take the used font into account. But you will get a warning by package `typearea` if there are clearly too many or too few characters in a normal text line.

With `DIV=calc` takes the chosen font and its characteristics (width of the characters etc.) into account.

---

**Update**

There was a bug in `typearea`: until (including) version 3.24 the standard `DIV` values for fontsizes `10pt` (`DIV=8`), `11pt` (`DIV=10`) and `12pt` (`DIV=12`) were used even if the paper format was not `A4`. This bug will be fixed in version 3.25. So if you use a version before 3.25 and not the default `paper=a4` Option then an explicit `DIV=calc` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the algorithm used by DIV=calc does not give the same value as the standard value when applied to a paper format and font size that already exist in the database ?

Comment: For me DIV=calc shoul result in the same values as the standards (if it really optimizes the margins). So, what is the best ,using DIV=default or DIV=calc for my example?

Comment: It depends. If there is no warning both is fine. Lower `DIV` values results in bigger page margins. If you select a different font or if you change the space between the lines for the document (eg. using package `setspace`) then add a `\recalctypearea` at the end of your preamble.

Comment: Just one more question please, The margins of the text area seem not to move for me when I change the DIV value. Please, check my example in Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/13501147mykxypkstsrw#/52131268/

Comment: There (Overleaf) you are using package `geometry` to set the margins ;-) This overwrites the KOMA-Script settings. (I have downloaded the log file)